# How to obtain a random sample of 100K users with all their transactions in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a huge dataset containing information on millions of users and their purchases recorded for 1 year. Is there a way to create a random sample of 100K users (keeping all their individual purchases) from this data? Since a user can have more than one purchase, the sample will contain more than 100k records.
I was able to find the `rand()` function but it does not give me all records for the users.

I tried this query:

```
select *
from mytable
where rand()< 0.025 and mydate between '20140101' and '20141231'
distribute by rand()
sort by rand()
limit 100000
```

This result produces only the 100k random records and not *all* the records for these 100k users.

Any suggestions on how to write a hive query to obtain this results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create table of 100,000 random userIDs first:

```
CREATE table Random_Users AS 
  Select * From (Select distinct userId From my table) users 
  where rand()< 0.025 limit 100000;
```

Then you can do

```
Select mytable.* From mytable m JOIN random_users r ON (m.userId = r.userId);
```